# Automatic import Excel/CSV file from local pc to QuickBase without using third-party of quickbase

Tags: quickbase

I want to import excel/csv file from local pc to quickbase and update table without using third-party apps of quickbase connected services and update automatically whenever any change in excel/csv.

Comment: If you don't want to use a third party app you will need to write your own code to automate the import through the QuickBase API / CSV Import

Comment: can you explain more by providing code

Comment: In what language? You can use just about any language. Php, nodejs, golang, python, c#, est.